# How to set String value to spinner from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

Here is my requirement i need to set string from sqlite and to assign it to spinner really confused how to do this when i click edit button here it will go to next activity here i will retrieve all value i have set value to edittext but cannot set value to spinner how can i do this so far what i have tried is:

```
    RequestQueue queue_company_name = Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());
    final ArrayList<Model_Account> arrayobj_company_name = new ArrayList<Model_Account>();
    String Url_company_name = "http://xxx/xxx/xxx/AcoountCreatePageLoad.svc/Account/Accouxxxt";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest_company_name = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url_company_name, new JSONObject(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String server_response = response.toString();
                    try {
                        JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(server_response);
                        JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_object.getString("AccountPageLoadAccountListResult"));
                        for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                            Model_Account model_spinner = new Model_Account();
                            JSONObject json_arrayJSONObject = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                            model_spinner.setName(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyName"));
                            model_spinner.setCompanyname(json_arrayJSONObject.getInt("AccountID"));
                            arrayobj_company_name.add(model_spinner);

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

    //Creating request queue

    queue_company_name.add(jsonObjRequest_company_name);

    ArrayAdapter<Model_Account> company_names = new ArrayAdapter<Model_Account>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayobj_company_name);
    spinner_company_name.setAdapter(company_names);
final Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extra != null) {

    id = extra.getInt("id");

    Cursor edit_accnt = account_sf_db.getData(id);
    if (edit_accnt.moveToFirst()) {
        do {


            compny_group.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.company_groups)));
            company_name.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Parent_company)));
            addrss1.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Address_line1)));
            address_2.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Address_line2)));
            address_3.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Address_line3)));
            pin_code.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Pincode)));
            land_line.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Landline1)));
            landline_2.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Landline2)));
            url.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Url)));
            email.setText(edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndex(Model_Account.Landline2)));
            String match = edit_accnt.getString(edit_accnt.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Model_Account.Company_name));
            Log.e("test",match);
        } while (edit_accnt.moveToNext());



    }
}
```

how to set that match to adapter company names struggling with this can someonehelp me!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get the position of the string you want to set to spinner using adapter

```
int position = spinnerAdapter.getPosition(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("CompanyName"));
```

after that, select in spinner with position

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: That would be because the position of string you want to set would be returned -1 indicating that spinner doesn't have that item

Comment: yeah that's what I told in the above comment. If spinner won't have the item you'll get it's position as -1.

Comment: then how to rectify it

Comment: Initially itself you have to set up all the data values to your spinner. And once you are calling API so in the response of the your API, you would be getting position of the data string from spinner using spinnerAdapter

Comment: then how to do this as new for this am struggling with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105106/discussion-between-mayank-bhatnagar-and-yog).